# How do I add a line break to an external text log file from a pentaho transform?

Tags: pentaho, pdi, spoon

I'm using pentaho pdi (spoon) I have a transform to compare 2 database tables (from a query selecting year and quarters within those tables), i'm then hoping to a merge rows (diff) to a filter rows if flagfield is not identical, which if success logs the matches, and if doesn't match logs the output, both with text file output steps...

my issue is my external log file gets appended and looks like this:

```
412542 - 21 - 4 - deleted - DOMAIN1
461623 - 22 - 1 - deleted - DOMAIN1 
^failuresDOMAIN1  - 238388 - 12 - 4 - identical
DOMAIN1- 223016 - 13 - 1 - identical
DOMAIN1- 171764 - 13 - 2 - identical
DOMAIN1- 185569 - 13 - 3 - identical
DOMAIN1- 232247 - 13 - 4 - identical
DOMAIN1- 260057 - 14 - 1 - identical
^successes
```

I want this output:

```
412542 - 21 - 4 - deleted - DOMAIN1
461623 - 22 - 1 - deleted - DOMAIN1 
^failures

DOMAIN1  - 238388 - 12 - 4 - identical
DOMAIN1- 223016 - 13 - 1 - identical
DOMAIN1- 171764 - 13 - 2 - identical
DOMAIN1- 185569 - 13 - 3 - identical
DOMAIN1- 232247 - 13 - 4 - identical
DOMAIN1- 260057 - 14 - 1 - identical
^successes
```

notice the line breaks between the successes and failures

Answer (score 0):

using add a data grid w/ a "line_break" string that's simply a new line, then passing that to each "text file output" that logs as this "line_break" data column string value quickly which helps, but I can't seem to sequence the transform steps because they're parallel...

Comment: Just use a "block this step until steps finish" to force order between parallel steps, to sequence the transform steps.